# Using related_name twice

Tags: django

Suppose I have 3 models which are subsequent 1 to many relations, A (1 to many) B (1 to many) C:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', related_name='re_model_b')

class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_b = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', related_name='re_model_c')
```

Starting from a ModelA instance I can use:

```
model_a.re_model_b
```

to obtain the ModelB related objects. But from there I don't know how to get to ModelC. I tried:

```
model_a.re_model_b.re_model_c
```

and:

```
model_a.re_model_b__re_model_c
```

neither of which seems to do the trick.

Comment: First question, is it supposed to be a one-to-many relation or were you trying to create a one-to-one?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'it' is refering to but both relations mentioned here, from a to b and from b to c are 1 to many. I suppose the implicit relation from a to c is also a 1 to many.

Comment: If they're supposed to be one-to-many than this result is expected. `model_a.re_model_b` is a collection of items, not a single item.

Comment: Looks like your attempt at making a B to C is actually an A to C. Try changing `model_b` to `models.ForeignKey('ModelB', related_name='re_model_c')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it in the exact form you're thinking of (`model_a.re_model_b.re_model_c`). Since `model_a.re_model_b` returns an objects manager (and not an object itself), you can't use it in the same way. For example, `obj_a.re_model_b.all()` returns a queryset of related ModelB objects.

Instead, it probably makes more sense to do `ModelC.objects.filter(model_b__model_a=my_obj_a)`.